# Break Lock after Tortoise crashes

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

When i was commiting a folder when the Tortoise Crashed.
I moved the code, did another checkout, pasted my modification file again and tried to commit.

I got the error below:

> Error: Commit failed (details follow):
>   Error: Cannot verify lock on path 
>   Error:  ; no matching lock-token available
>   Error: If you want to break the lock, use the 'Check For Modifications' dialog or the repository browser.

I tried to find the Release Lock button, but it dosen't appear.
I tried to "Check for modifications", and right-click on the folder for "Break Lock" without success.
I also tried to lock the file again and i got the error:

> "Error:  locked by user '' in filesystem '...\repository\db'"

Can i remove the lock deleting some file in svn folder?

EDIT:
When i tried to do what Bert told me i Tortoise Crashed again
Problem:

> Event Name:   BEX
>
> Application Name: TortoiseProc.exe
>
> Application Version:  1.7.1.22161
>
> Fault Module Name:    saslDIGESTMD5.dll
>
> Fault Version Name:   2.1.24.0
>
> Exception Code:   c0000005
>
> Debug error: saslDIGESTMD5.dll!7333c86a() Unknown

Comment: Open a console window, and switch to your working directory. Now type in the command line `svn cleanup`. That should fix your issues. I don't know where the TortoiseSVN cleanup command is, or if it has one.

Comment: The svn cleanup dosen't do anything. And i got the same problem again using console. :(

Comment: What if you do a `svn update` and then an `svn status` on the command line. That should point out which files are giving you problems. If the `svn status` is showing certain files as locked, you can try a `svn unlock --force` on those files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This errors is not about the working copy lock, but about an explicitly obtained lock using `svn lock`

Did you get an exact path in your error message?

In that case you can do a

```
svn lock --force PATH -m "Steal lock"
```

To steal the lock that was originally stored in the other working copy.

```
svn status -u
```

should also show you which files are locked in the repository.

Comment: Hey Bert. It was a good ideia. Now i can reproduce the crash in Tortoise. I added the error in my question. Now ill try to update tortoise.